# Why yocto build x86 sysroots when I build raspberrypi?

Tags: build, raspberry-pi, yocto

I made RaspberryPi minimum image via Yocto.
I just followed the instructions in the below article.

http://www.cnx-software.com/2013/07/05/12mb-minimal-image-for-raspberry-pi-using-the-yocto-project/

It makes a suitable image for RaspberryPi and rpi sysroots. But, it also makes x86_64 sysroots. If those are not created, Build time would be more shorter.

Why it makes x86_64 binaries when it makes ARM images?

```
$ ls build/tmp/sysroots
raspberrypi  raspberrypi-tcbootstrap  x86_64-linux

$ ls x86_64-linux/
bin  etc  lib  sbin  usr  var

$ find -name sysroots
./build/tmp/work/armv6-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/binutils-cross/.../sysroots
...
./build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/.../sysroots
./build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/.../tmp/sysroots
...
./build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/sqlite3-native/.../sysroots
...
./build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/openssl-native/.../sysroots
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you see all packages built for the x86_64 architecture have the `-native` ending. Those native packages are needed by other packages for cross-compilation. For example you need a native compiler on your x86_64 to build your cross-compiler. This cross-compiler also has to be native to compile binaries for your target. The same goes for some libraries and tools (all you see in your `build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/` directory).
So there are not all packages you selected for your raspberry image built native but only the ones Yocto needs for the cross-compilation.

Furthermore Yocto builds packages only if it has detected changes in them.
Therefore you "lose" the build time only for packages which weren't built already or changed since the last build.

For more information on this topic take a look at the functional principle of the Yocto cross toolchain generation [1].

[1] https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#cross-development-toolchain-generation